# 3 tables join with one as bridge between them

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with students/school info.

```
*students* table has ID | First Name | Last Name  
*classes* table has  ID | Class Name | Department
*matrix* table has   ID |class_id | student_id
```

I need to make a query and get all students, all classes, and NULL where there is no match in the *matrix* table. The *matrix* table is basically where I write which class each student is registered in.

I used

```
SELECT *
FROM matrix
LEFT JOIN students AS students ON matrix.student_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN classes AS classes ON matrix.class_id = classes.id
```

But that just returns the students that have matching subjects. I need also student that have no matching class.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc9bf/2/0

In the fiddle I would expect *Johanna* to also show up in the query with NULL | NULL in respective `class_id` and `student_id`

Comment: left join starting from `students` not `matrix` solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join should be done with `students` as left table

```
select * from students s
 left join matrix m on m.student_id = s.id
 left join classes c on c.id = m.class_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc9bf/4

Comment: Thank you Abhik. My logic was wrong, starting with students didn't make sense to me but now I understand how to think.